# Can a spacecraft be sent into orbit using magnetic propulsion?

Tags: magnetic-fields

Can a rocket potentially be sent to orbit using magnetic force? For example, If I attach two powerful magnets to a light spacecraft, will the resulting magnetic force be enough to move it?

Comment: Can force cause an object to move? Absolutely! Yes. It can. Spacecraft? Magnets? etc? That sounds like engineering, not physics. (P.S., There's not enough information in your question for anybody else to get a clear picture of what you are thinking, but if I was a betting man, I would bet that whatever it is, it won't work.)

Answer (score 1):

> Can a rocket potentially be sent to orbit using magnetic force?

This would be difficult.  Magnetic forces fall off quickly with distance, and rockets need to move very quickly.  So it's hard to keep sufficient forces on them.

> If I attach two powerful magnets to a light spacecraft, will the resulting magnetic force be enough to move it?

You'd need to better describe what you're proposing.  If you're asking that the field from the two interacting magnets will do something useful, it will not.  You would need magnets on the rocket to interact with some field generated by an object other than the rocket.

The earth's magnetic field is present, but far too weak and uniform to be used for propulsion by interaction with permanent magnets.  You could surround the rocket with a controlled magnetic field (by building a tower of electromagnets or similar), but you can only build the tower so high.  After leaving the top of the tower, the rocket is not yet in orbit, but is receiving no more forces.